# No controlo JS, ¿sugerencias?

Tags: javascript

Si quito la segunda función (slidetoggle2), funciona bien el mostrar el texto del primer botón (slidetoggle). He copiado ese código de JS de una página en la que solo hay un botón para "seguir leyendo", pero al añadir otro texto y querer hacer lo mismo, no me muestra ningun resultado. Necesito una mano experta, gracias

Mi código JS

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.slidetoggle').on('click', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $('.slideblock').slideToggle('slow', function(event){
        if($(this).is(':visible')){
          $('.slidetoggle').html('Ocultar <span>&#9650;</span>');
        } else {
          $('.slidetoggle').html('Mostrar <span>&#9660;</span>');
        }
      });
    });
    $('.slidetoggle2').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.slideblock2').slideToggle2('slow', function(event){
          if($(this).is(':visible')){
            $('.slidetoggle2').html('Hide <span>&#9650;</span>');
          } else {
            $('.slidetoggle2').html('Show <span>&#9660;</span>');
          }
        });
<!-- MI HTML -->
    
});
```

```html
<div class="slidepanel">
<div class="slideblock">
    <p> Parrafo >

</div>
<a href="#" class="slidetoggle">Mostrar</a>
</div>


<div class="slidepanel-2">
<div class="slideblock-2">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, error tempore numquam illum blanditiis atque architecto nesciunt harum eveniet. Deleniti laboriosam asperiores fuga eum id voluptatem voluptate modi veritatis ipsam. <p/>
</div>
<a href="#" class="slidetoggle-2">Mostrar texto</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los selectores de tu segundo slidepanel están incorrectos, si te fijas en el HTML los tienes con un guión slidetoggle-2 y en tu JavaScript .slidetoggle2, lo mismo con todos los demás.

```
$('.slidetoggle-2').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.slideblock-2').slideToggle('slow', function (event) {
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
            $('.slidetoggle-2').html('Hide <span>&#9650;</span>');
        } else {
            $('.slidetoggle-2').html('Show <span>&#9660;</span>');
        }
    });
});
```

Código:

```js
  $(document).ready(function (e) {   
        $(".slideblock").slideToggle("hide");
        $(".slideblock-2").slideToggle("show");

        $('.slidetoggle').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.slideblock').slideToggle('slow', function (event) {
                if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                    $('.slidetoggle').html('Ocultar <span>&#9650;</span>');
                } else {
                    $('.slidetoggle').html('Mostrar <span>&#9660;</span>');
                }
            });
        });
        
        $('.slidetoggle-2').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.slideblock-2').slideToggle('slow', function (event) {
                if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                    $('.slidetoggle-2').html('Ocultar <span>&#9650;</span>');
                } else {
                    $('.slidetoggle-2').html('Mostrar <span>&#9660;</span>');
                }
            });
        }); 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slidepanel">
    <div class="slideblock">
        <p> Parrafo </p>

    </div>
    <a href="#" class="slidetoggle">Mostrar</a>
</div>

<div class="slidepanel-2">
    <div class="slideblock-2">
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, error tempore numquam illum blanditiis atque
            architecto nesciunt harum eveniet. Deleniti laboriosam asperiores fuga eum id voluptatem voluptate modi
            veritatis ipsam.
        </p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="slidetoggle-2">Mostrar texto</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias. Lo he modificado pero sigue igual. No me funcionan los "botones". Como no se si me he explicado antes, al pulsar un "boton" de "leer mas" debe mostrar un texto con la descrip. y despues está el de contraer dicha descrip. Al añadir el mismo codigo js cambiando esos selectores, ya no me muestra ninguna descrip. ni del primero ni del segundo. Puedo enviar de nuevo el codigo

Comment: Actualice la respuesta con codigo, tu ejemplo lanza unos errores de javascript de que no cierras correctamente funciones. Aunque no se si sea esa la funcionalidad que quieres, simplemente ejecuto el toggle al principio para ocultarlos por default. Nos dices.

Comment: Solucionado. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Cuando actualizo la pagina se muestran desplegados, es decir, el boton de ocultar texto esta activado (mostrando el texto), para que aparezcan los botones con el  Mostrar y no se vea la descripcion, como seria? Gracias

Comment: Esta raro, porque para eso se puso el  $(".slideblock").slideToggle("show"); al principio del codigo para que no aparesca asi.

Comment: No sé si tendra que ver el navegador que utilizo, google chrome, y visual studio code. Lo he solucionado quitando las dos primeras lineas [ $(".slideblock").slideToggle("hide");
        $(".slideblock-2").slideToggle("show");]. y asi funciona como debe. Una ultima consulta. Como podria hacer para que al pulsar sobre otro boton del otro apartado, se cierre el que esté activo (o "mostrado). Gracias de nuevo